# Unable to get the value of ASPX Checkboxlist inside Update Panel that are checked using JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I have 3 pop ups inside an `UpdatePanel`. The first pop up contains `RadioButtonList` selecting which generates the `RadioButtonList` in the 2nd Pop Up. Upon selecting the radio button from 2nd pop populates the `CheckBoxList` "chkListSafetyStandards". On clicking the close button of this 3rd pop up I wish to get the text and value of the check boxes that are checked.

The ASPX Markup is as follows:

```
 <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS ACTION TAKEN [END]-->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPnlPopUpsObsCatAndSubCat" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS CATEGORY [START]-->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnObservationCategory" PostBackUrl="#" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-primary"
            Style="display: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
            data-target="#modalSelectObsCat" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalSelectObsCat">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-blue">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;</span></button>
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title">
                                <label>
                                    Select Observation Category
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">
                                <div class="row modalBodyHeightForVisitedWith">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbListObservationCategory" onclick="getObsCategory();showLoader();closeModal();return true;"
                                            CssClass="radio-list-custom" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbListObservationCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server">
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS CATEGORY [END]-->
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS SUB CATEGORY [START]-->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnObservationSubCategory" PostBackUrl="#" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-primary"
            Style="display: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
            data-target="#modalSelectObsSubCat" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <%--  <a id="lnkBtnObservationSubCategory" href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="display: none;"
            data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#modalSelectObsSubCat" />--%>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalSelectObsSubCat">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-blue">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;</span></button>
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title">
                                <label>
                                    Select Observation Sub Category
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">
                                <div class="row modalBodyHeightForVisitedWith">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbListObservationSubCategory" onclick="getObsSubCategory();closeModal();"
                                            CssClass="radio-list-custom" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbListObservationSubCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server">
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS SUB CATEGORY [END]-->
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS SAFETY STANDARDS [START]-->
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnSafetyStandards" PostBackUrl="#" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-primary"
            Style="display: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
            data-target="#modalSelectSafetyStandards" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <%--  <a id="lnkBtnObservationSubCategory" href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" style="display: none;"
            data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#modalSelectObsSubCat" />--%>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalSelectSafetyStandards">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-blue">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="getObsSafetyStandards();closeModal();"
                                aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;</span></button>
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title">
                                <label>
                                    Select Safety Standards
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">
                                <div class="row modalBodyHeightForVisitedWith">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkListSafetyStandards" CssClass="chk-list-custom" runat="server">
                                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <!--MODAL POP FOR SELECTING OBS SAFETY STANDARDS [END]-->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Upon selecting the checkboxes the `[checked="checked"]` markup does not reflect on the page and so I am unable to capture the checked checkbox using JavaScript. I cannot remove the `UpdatePanel` as that causes the entire page to reload loading the first tab (I am using this check box in the 2nd Tab). Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: If you see the checkboxes, it means the markup is on the page. Can you show us the js code you are using trying to access this markup, perhaps the problem hides there?

Answer (score 0):

Exmaple of how you can get checked values:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkListSafetyStandards" CssClass="chk-list-custom" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="option 1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="option 2" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="option 3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>

    <script>
        function getChecked() {
            var checked = $('input[id*="chkListSafetyStandards"]:checked');
            checked.each(function (index, value) {
                console.log($(value).attr("id"));
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The problem isn't that I am unable to get the checked checkbox. But the "checked" attribute isn't getting reflected when the check box list is inside the update panel. I didn't find any solution other than pushing the logic to the codebehind page. Thanks in any case Hanks. :-)